# Can't edit any thing from my WordPress dashboard anymore

Tags: wordpress

I have a big problem. I cant do any thing from my dashboard anymore. It was working fine few minutes ago any now i can't install plugins, i can't edit any files in editor, cant edit any page or post.

Please help.

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: More info for help you is needed , what error/behavior  is having , what is the last thing you remember you did..

Comment: When i try to install any plugin it writes.   Installation failed: The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Comment: I was editing stylesheet.css and header.php

Comment: is your host dedicated , shared or vps? can you check if you have disk free space?

Comment: I dont know any thing about dedicated, shared and vps.    I am currently using free hosting service by ultimatefreehost.in

Comment: I am able yo delete plugin, or line of code. But i can't add any thing

Comment: firstly get calm , probably your free host has run out free space , so can you check first it in your provider acount / login to confirm the if this is the reason? after we can try to solve...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what are you saying. My english is not good.    Are you asking for my account username and password?

Comment: No no , i'm trying to explain , log in to your ultimatefreehost.in account , and then find disk space usage ...

Comment: The hosting service i am using gives me unlimited bandwidth and space.

Comment: Then also i cleared some space, but no change.

Comment: Ok.  I think it shloud change my hosting service.     I am planing to buy godaddy hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

That error can be caused due following reasons :

- -uploading an invalid zip .. or corrupted . ( check for password protection )
- -not enough free space in server
- -larger files can do crash it!